# Joining tables without a common column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

TABLE1

```
ID  
----                        
1                           
2                           
3                           
4                           
5
```

TABLE2

```
Name
----
Z
Y
X
W
V
```

Expected Output:

```
ID              Name
-------------------------
1               NULL
2               NULL
3               NULL
4               NULL
5               NULL
NULL             Z
NULL             Y
NULL             X
NULL             W
NULL             V
```

I need a solution for the above scenario by using JOINS in SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **[`FULL OUTER JOIN`](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-full-outer-join.php)**, you can get the expected result.

Since there are no common fields, no records from Table1 should match with Table2 and vice versa. So perhaps `ON 0 = 1` as the join condition also will work as expected. [Thanks Bart Hofland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035286/joining-tables-without-a-common-column-in-sql-server/56036189?noredirect=1#comment98715197_56036189)

So the query below also will work:

```
SELECT T1.Id, T2.[Name]
FROM Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON 0 = 1;
```

or

```
SELECT T1.Id, T2.[Name]
FROM Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.[Name] = CAST(T1.Id AS VARCHAR(2));
```

Demo with the sample data:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Id INT);

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Id) VALUES
(1),                           
(2),                           
(3),                           
(4),                           
(5);  

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE ([Name] VARCHAR(1));

INSERT INTO @Table2 ([Name]) VALUES
('Z'),
('Y'),
('X'),
('W'),
('V');

SELECT T1.Id, T2.[Name]
FROM @Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN @Table2 T2 ON 0 = 1;
```

Output:

```
Id      Name
-----------------
1       NULL
2       NULL
3       NULL
4       NULL
5       NULL
NULL    Z
NULL    Y
NULL    X
NULL    W
NULL    V
```

Comment: Using a FULL OUTER JOIN does the trick, but the logic that matches the records should be altered. Since there are no common fields, no records from table 1 should match with table 2 and vice versa, I think. So perhaps `ON 0 = 1` as the join condition will work as expected.

Comment: @BartHofland Yes, valid point. Let me update in the answer, with your comment reference.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why  you'd want this, but to get your expected results you could do this. This is not a join, though.

```
SELECT ID, NULL as NAME from Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NAME from Table2
```

Edited to add

Since the question specifically requests a solution with a join, Arulkumar's answer of FULL OUTER JOIN is a better fit, and you don't have to worry about what the column data types are.

Comment: In this specific case, your query will probably work fine. However, to be sure, I normally would explicitly cast the NULL value for `NAME` in the first SELECT query to the type of the `NAME` column of `Table2`. (Otherwise, the second query might fail on a conversion error.) However, the OP did not provide info about the data types, so that's not possible here. ;-) Perhaps newer SQL Server versions handle implicit conversions better, but I'm not sure.