# Joining 2 Queries without Common Column Fields in SQL?

Tags: sql

My issue is in reference to a similar post:
[Joining tables without a common column in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035286/joining-tables-without-a-common-column-in-sql-server)

I have 2 queries, each query references different tables, hence the queries do not have common column fields.

I want to join the 2 queries together. Let's take for example the 2 queries has the following data:

Query1

```
Test1           Test2
-----------     -------------
A               1
B               2
C               3
```

Query2

```
Test3           Test4
-----------     -------------
D               4
E               5
F               6
```

Expected Query3:

```
Test1           Test2             Test3            Test4
-----------     -------------     -------------    -------------
A               1                                     
B               2                                     
C               3                  
                                  D                4
                                  E                5
                                  F                6
```

The provided answer to the similar post is referenced here: [Using Full Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036189/2373410)

I've tried the recommended solution like so:

```
SELECT Query1.Test1, Query1.Test2, Query2.[Test3], Query2.[Test4]
FROM Query1
FULL OUTER JOIN Query2 ON 0 = 1;
```

However, I get an error in Microsoft Access stating:

```
Syntax error in FROM clause.
```

Can someone give me some guidance on what I did wrong and what the solution would be?

Comment: Did you try with cross join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying `Full Outer Join` but it does not exist on `MySQL`.
We can emulate it by doing a UNION of a left join and a right join

Try:

```
create table query1(
  test1 varchar(5), 
  test2 int(3)  );

insert into query1 values ( 'A', 1),( 'B', 2),( 'C', 3);

create table query2(
  test3 varchar(5), 
  test4 int(3)  );

insert into query2 values ( 'D', 4),( 'E', 5),( 'F', 6);



SELECT *
FROM `query1` as `t1`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `query2` as `t2` ON `t1`.`test1` = `t2`.`test3`   
UNION  
SELECT *
FROM `query1` as `t1`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `query2` as `t2` ON `t1`.`test1` = `t2`.`test3` ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/69

Comment: Sorry wrong tag, it's updated now, it should be SQL

Comment: @Pangu Which RDBMS you mean `SQL` ?

Comment: also wanted to add that `Test1` and `Test2` are not the same data type, it was just an example I was using.

Comment: @Pangu it doesn't matter, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will return all the records in the left table , `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` will return all the records on the right table and in the end you do a `UNION` for all the datas. You can try based on your values and let me know

Comment: I apologize for fatty fingers, I meant to say `Test1` and `Test3` since I see you used `test1` = `t2`.`test3`. I think this is giving me a `Type mismatch in expression` error.

Comment: @Pangu i used that because the data type must be equal, `int` to `int` or `varchar` to `varchar` . Is the same if I use test2 with test4 https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/71

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237552/discussion-between-pangu-and-ergest-basha).

Comment: please join chat

Answer (score 0):

If you want that exact final column structure, you could use union but first you should edit your query adding 2 empty values for 'Test3' and 'Test4' in the first query and 'Test1' and 'Test2' in the second.

First query

```
SELECT Test1, Test2, '' as Test3, '' as Test4 FROM someTable
```

Second query

```
SELECT '' as Test1, '' as Test2, Test3, Test4 FROM someTable
```

Then you can do the UNION

```
Query1 

UNION

Query2
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion in my `Query3` but I got an error stating `The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect`. I actually combined both `SELECT` statements and `UNION` them in my `Query3` instead of modifying the original `Query1` and `Query2`. Does it matter?

Comment: Could you post your query?

Comment: @Pangu If separate queries works well then simply enclose them with parenthesis in UNION : `( {Query 1 text} ) UNION ALL ( {Query 2 text} )`.

Comment: @SergioRinaudo Query3: `SELECT Test1, Test2, '' As Test3, '' As Test4 FROM Query1 UNION SELECT '' As Test1, '' As Test2, Test3, Test4 FROM Query2;`